# Is there a way in React to change a prop type to avoid TypeErrors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, properties

I'm wondering if there's a way to change a prop type if the one that is being passed isn't of the type expected.

For example, if my component expects to receive an object (Using PropTypes or using TypeScript notation), but an array is passed, that array should be converted into an object (It can be an empty object).

Is there a way to archive this?

Example:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3];

<Component name={array} />
```

Then inside of my component:

```
const Component({ name }) {

    console.log(typeof name);
    // output: 'string'  

    console.log(name);
    // output: ''

    return (
        <div />
    );
}

Component.propTypes = {
   name: PropTypes.string
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your question using some code?

Comment: @AjeetShah does that example help?

Comment: The answers below should help you. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). Documented as:

> A major part of software engineering is building components that not only have well-defined and consistent APIs, but are also reusable. Components that are capable of working on the data of today as well as the data of tomorrow will give you the most flexible capabilities for building up large software systems.
>
> In languages like C# and Java, one of the main tools in the toolbox for creating reusable components is generics, that is, being able to create a component that can work over a variety of types rather than a single one. This allows users to consume these components and use their own types.

You can then convert to the desired type:

```
const convert2Array = <T>(prop: T): T[] => {
    let arr: T[];
    if (Array.isArray(prop)) {
        arr = prop;
    } else if (typeof prop === 'object' && prop !== null) {
        arr = Object.values(prop);
    } else {
        arr = [prop];
    } 

    return arr;
};

convert2Array('str'); // ['str']
convert2Array(7); // [7]
convert2Array(['an', 'existing', 'array']); // ['an', 'existing', 'array']
convert2Array({foo: 'bar', zip: 'zap'}); // ['bar', 'zap']
```

Answer (score 0):

`array` is a subtype of `object`, so passing an `array` as an `object` is fine in typescript already.

Regarding other prop conversions: you can do this with a higher-order component that takes the "expanded" props and maps them to their expected types.  The typescript types for that aren't too hard.  The part where this got tricky is writing it in such a way that the javascript code knows which props to convert, since typescript types are erased at runtime.

The solution that I came up with requires that you specify the keys of the props to convert.  It's not the most elegant thing I've ever written but it works!

```
const withExpandedProps = <Keys extends string, Converter extends (value: any) => any>(
  keys: Keys[],
  convert: Converter
) => <Props extends {}>(Component: React.ComponentType<Props>) => (
  props: Omit<Props, Keys> & Record<Keys, Expanded<Converter>>
) => {
  const newProps = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(props).map(([key, value]) => {
      const mappedVal = (keys as string[]).includes(key)
        ? convert(value as any)
        : value;
      return [key, mappedVal];
    })
  ) as Props;

  return <Component {...newProps} />;
};
```

Used as:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  num: number;
  str: string;
  obj: object;
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({ num, str, obj }) => {
  console.log({ num, str, obj });
  return (
    <div>
      <div>#{num}</div>
      <div>{str}</div>
      <ul>
        {Object.keys(obj).map((key) => (
          <li key={key}>{key}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const NewComponent = withExpandedProps(
  // all variables in javascript have a toString property
  ["str"],
  (value: any) => value.toString()
)(
  withExpandedProps(
    // convert strings to numbers -- might return NaN which is type number
    ["num"],
    (value: string | number) =>
      typeof value === "string" ? parseFloat(value) : value
  )(MyComponent)
);

const Test = () => (
  <NewComponent
    num={"5"} // string | number
    str={["one", "two"]} // any
    obj={["one", "two"]} // object
  />
);
```

(will edit with more explanation later)